# C#: Creating of float variable on the fly

Tags: c#, reflection

I have 2 strings: "3.45" and "float" so it means that I need to create a variable of float type with value = 3.45. How to do that? I guess I need to use Reflection but I cannot figure out how to assign the float variable from the string.
NB Actually both strings can have any values. I need some universal code that will work with any type.

Thanks

Comment: Try to accept some answers from your questions. That is how this website is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make take a look at the [ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method:

```
string s1 = "3.45";
string s2 = "System.Single";
Type targetType = Type.GetType(s2, true);
object result = Convert.ChangeType(s1, targetType);
```

And yet another one:

```
string s1 = "08/12/2010";
string s2 = "System.DateTime";
Type targetType = Type.GetType(s2, true);
object result = Convert.ChangeType(s1, targetType);
```

To handle culture specific conversions like decimal separator, datetime format there's an [overload of this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx) that you need to use in order to pass a format provider:

```
string s1 = "3,45";
string s2 = "System.Single";
Type targetType = Type.GetType(s2, true);
object result = Convert.ChangeType(s1, targetType, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChangeType to accomplish this

```
        string test = "12.2";
        var sam = Type.GetType("System.Single");    
        var val = Convert.ChangeType(test, sam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create a "variable" of float/single type?

I think you want to do something with the value. Think about what you want to do with it.

If you need to pass it to another variable you can use:

```
object someValue = single.Parse("3.45");
```

If you want to call a method through reflection using a float as a dynamic parameter, you can use (credits to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) for most of the example):

```
    Type magicType = Type.GetType("MagicClass");
    ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});

    // Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of single 3.45

    MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
    object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{ single.Parse("3.45")});
```